# Can all go libraries now be run outside of GOPATH?

Tags: go

I read that go libraries no longer are forced to be saved under the GOPATH directory.

Do I have to modify libraries that are older or this just works for all libraries now assuming you have the correct version of Go?

Comment: You should link the piece of documentation where you read this

Comment: You don't need to modify packages that are older. New packages outside of GOPATH do need a go.mod file.

Comment: You might want to clarify your terms - a "library" is generally code you can import, not a program you can run; so "can all go libraries by run outside gopath" really the answer is "no" because libraries can't be run anywhere. Go programs are self-contained and CAN be run anywhere, and have been able to since Go 1.0 - you don't need GOPATH, you don't even need Go installed, to run a compiled Go program.

Comment: Libraries don't run, anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A project using Go modules doesn't need to be under GOPATH (but you still need one for the package cache). A project using Go modules can import any library, whether or not that library uses Go modules.

A project NOT using Go modules must reside under GOPATH.